# sortin low to high and high to low by php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pdo, price

I have this code:

```
$mtp->query("SELECT * FROM `shop_small_pro_tbl` order by price ASC");
$records=$mtp->resultset();

foreach($records as $row) {
      $a= $row['price'] ;   
     echo $a;       
}
```

When I output the prices, it looks like this:

```
1050000 1290000 1600000 1820000 1910000 2110000 2130000 2360000 2410000 680000 900000
```

Comment: What is the data type of the price column? Make sure it should be a numeric data type.

Comment: looks to me like the price column is a `VARCHAR` and it should be an `INT`

Answer (score 0):

Your price column is being "unnaturally sorted"  For more information see this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-sorting/).

The best/permanent way to fix this is to make the `price` column in your database: `DECIMAL(10,2)`.  This assumes that you are actually storing the price value to 2 decimal places; otherwise you could use `INT` if the values are merely integers. By modifying your database table structure, you won't have to worry with re-CASTing your column type when querying.

If you have a project-specific reason why your table column's type cannot be altered, then you can CAST the price column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `shop_small_pro_tbl` ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: thanks , I use this and work well

SELECT * FROM `shop_small_pro_tbl` ORDER BY CAST(price  AS DECIMAL(10,2))